# Keycloak authorization service for REST application without keycloak adapter

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I was checking keycloak authorization service to implement authorization service for few of the REST endpoints which do not have keycloak adapter implemented.

From keycloak quick starts example it looks like authorization service only supported for end points which has keycloak adapter implemented.

Has any one tried to perform keycloak authentication to a REST request before request actually goes to that server.

The REST endpoints are written in Node.JS and i can't implement the adapter in Node.JS because it is not maintained by us. :)

Comment: Keycloak is strongly linked to the OpenId Connect protocol, which you can use to securize any web application, even without using an adapter. The keycloak adapters are small utility libraries which are meant to help you integrating your application with keycloak, but you could write that code yourself. Then you have two choices, use the NodeJs adapter or implement an adapter yourself, I think that going with the first one looks wiser. If you don't want to touch the application, you could also use the keycloak proxy...

Comment: Keycloak proxy is marked as deprecated. In 4.3.0 download page. I see following
Keycloak Proxy *DEPRECATED*